# gl_PrimitiveID equivalent in vertex shader

Tags: glsl

is there any way I can query which primitive the current vertex belong inside a vertex shader? I'm using a TBO to output some data that I need to access inside a vertex shader, I can access this data inside the fragment shader using gl_PrimitiveID and it works fine but I can't find a way to do the same inside a vertex shader, gl_VertexID/3 won't work for me because I'm using glDrawElements.

thank you!

luiz

Answer (score 2):

#### This is impossible if you understand how vertex shader invocations work.

While it is true that the vertex shader has to be evaluated for every vertex in a primitive, the transformed clip-space value will be stored in a post-transform cache. As a result, a vertex shared by 10 different triangles may only be computed once (subsequent primitives that use said vertex will hit the post-T&L cache first). There is no clear relationship between the primitive that caused the vertex to be computed and the vertex shader invocation.

The Geometry Shader stage, on the other hand, has `gl_PrimitiveIDIn`, which may help you - it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish.